# similar function to autopost back

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu

hi i need a function for WPF application is similar to the autopostback option in asp.net. what happens is i have a form with a combobox populated by xml file. so once user select "Others" as an option, a textbox and a button becomes visible for them. so is there anything wrong with my code? i used the compare string method to implement the function but seems like it is not working.

```
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Others")
        {
            BuilderemailTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            BuilderupdateButton.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            BuilderemailTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            BuilderupdateButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

i also tried the following, making changes to SelectedIndex too.

```
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)

{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() == "Others")
    {
        BuilderemailTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        BuilderupdateButton.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        BuilderemailTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        BuilderupdateButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

edit 1: My XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="309" Width="672">
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="23" Name="BuildButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Click="BuildButton_Click">Build</Button>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,63,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,0,0,140" Name="ExecbuildstartingmailCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="153">Exec Build Starting Mail</CheckBox>
        <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="0,63,173,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" />
        <Button Height="23" Margin="270,63,0,0" Name="BuilderupdateButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="51" Visibility="Hidden">Button</Button>
        <Button Height="23" Margin="0,63,73,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="74">Button</Button>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,63,0,0" Name="BuilderemailTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

edit2 my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
  <builderemail>
    <builder>
      <value>builder@example.com</value>
    </builder>
    <builder>
      <value>Others</value>
    </builder>
  </builderemail>
  <manageremail>
    <manager>
      <value>manager@example.com</value>
    </manager>
    <manager>
      <value>Others</value>
    </manager>
  </manageremail>
</email>
```

Comment: can you post your xaml definition ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your XML you can take the `SelectedItem`, cast it and access its properties. If your item has an `XmlElement` with the name `value`, which you want to test for "Other" you could try this:

```
(comboBox1.SelectedItem as XmlElement).GetElementsByTagName("value")[0].InnerText == "Other"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried it as if(comboBox1.SelectedItem as XmlElement).GetElementsByTagName("value")[0].InnerText == "Others" {do something} but it states ObjectReference not set to an instance of an object. i think something is missing. please advice! anyway my xml file is <email><builderemail><builder><value></value></builder><builder><value></value></builder></builderemail></email>